# Segmentation fault when calling fgets to read lines from file

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets, strtok

I'm getting a seg fault when after calling fgets about 20 times. I'm opening a file (does not return null). It is in the format:

```
 num1: value1
 num2: value2
 num3: value3
```

then reading lines from the file, storing values into an array, using nums as positions. Here is the code that seg faults:

edit: declaring myArray and line:

```
char myArray[3000];    
char * line;
char * word;

line = (char *) malloc(100);
word = (char *) malloc(16);

while(fgets(line, 99, file)) {
    printf("%s\n", line);
    word = strtok(line, " :");
    name = (int) strtol(word, NULL, 16);

    word = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    myArray[name] = word;
}
```

you'll notice I print out the line immediately after getting it. The file has 26 lines, but it only prints 23 line and then seg faults. Now, is it something I don't fully understand about fgets, or am I getting some synthax incorrect? I've tried allocating more memory to line, or more to word. I've also tried malloc -ing more memory after every call to strtok, but nothing seems to fix the seg fault.

Comment: Can you post more of your code? For example, what is the declaration of myArray?

Comment: also declaration of line array

Comment: There's no error checking on the return value from `strtok` nor is there bounds checking on the length of `word`.  Either could easily account for a seg fault.  Have you stepped through the code with a debugger?  That would likely tell you immediately where the problem lies.

Comment: In fact, a simple blank line at the end of the input file would crash your code.  I would bet that explains it.

Comment: you know.. that's very curious, I ran it with a debugger and it went past this issue, but again when I run the program normally it only prints out up to line 23 of 26 - and yes, I noticed only certain formatted files will work haha I guess I'm not quite sure how to solve this

Comment: would fgets not return null on a blank line? should I exit the loop on another condition?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: It would be extremely strange for your debugger not to hit the same issue... did you run it on the exact same input files (both with and without the debugger)?

By the way, you're assigning a `char *` to a `char` in `myArray[name] = word`. I'm pretty sure C takes the lowest byte of the RHS in that assignment.

Comment: According to the man page for fgets, it only returns NULL on a read error.  If it's returning NULL, there's something wrong.

You'd have to test it, but I'm fairly sure it returns an empty string "\0" on an empty line.  As a side note, don't cast malloc!

Comment: @Happington `fgets` also returns NULL on EOF

Comment: @Spudd86, not always.  If the EOF occurs before a newline, and after characters, the EOF indicator is set, but the function does NOT return a NULL.  I was referring to empty lines, not an EOF when I mentioned the empty string.  But yes, calling the function when EOF is already set will return a null.

Comment: @Happington I see, so would check for EOF like: 'while(fgets(line, 99, file) != EOF)' be a better way to run the loop, or maybe calling fgets before and inside the loop with 'while(line != EOF)'?

Comment: @roliu yes I'm really confused too, I checked a few times, it skips that segmentation fault completely, and continues to print the rest of the program.

Comment: `while(fgets(line, 99, file) != EOF)` is not correct... `fgets()` never returns EOF, it returns either the pointer you passed in or `NULL` what you need to do is make the inside of the loop deal with empty or badly formatted lines, then the check you have is fine.

Comment: What Spudd said is correct.  EOF (in c) is a numeric constant taken to be a negative integer (-1 in most cases.)  This means you can use it to compare in read functions that return an INTEGER of characters read, (see scanf() or fscanf().)  fgets() returns a char*, not an integer, so it will either be NULL, or a pointer to a location in memory.  Never the integer value EOF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems is the line `myArray[name] = word;` you're taking an array index from your input line and then setting the character at that position to low bits of the address of your word... I doubt that's actually what you want to do.

There's some other problems with your code, you're leaking the memory from the line `word = (char *) malloc(16);` because strtok returns a pointer into the string you initially pass it. You don't actually need to malloc anything for the code as written in the question, so you could have:

```
char myArray[3000];    
char line[100];
char *word = NULL;
```

`word` needs to be a pointer since it's holding the result of `strtok()`

You clearly don't understand pointers, you need to review that before you can understand why your code isn't working the way you expect.

If you say what your code is actually meant to be doing I can give you some hints on how to fix it, but at the moment I can't quite tell what the intended result is.

EDIT: Did you intend to read in your numbers in hexadecimal? The last argument to `strtol()` is the base to be used for conversion... you could also just use `atoi()`

so your loop could look like:

```
char myArray[3000];    
char line[100];
char *word = NULL;


while(fgets(line, 100, file)) {
    printf("%s\n", line);
    word = strtok(line, " :");
    if(word == NULL) continue;
    name = atoi(word); /* only if you didn't actually want hexadecimal */

    word = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    if(word == NULL) continue;

    if(name > 0 && name < 3000) { /* as I said in a comment below */
        strncpy(myArray + name, word, 3000 - name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! what I wanted to do was to read in a position before the colon and then a value after, and simply store them all in the array.

Comment: @StartedFromTheBottom You should be checking that the position is within bounds first... and did you want to copy the entire word into myArray starting at the given position? If so what you want is `strncpy(myArray + name, word, 3000 - name);` this will do that, and won't go past the end of myArray.